# How to write frontend (reagent) and backend (express.js) applications in a same clojurescript setup?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

**Can I write frontend (reagent) and backend (express.js) applications in a same clojurescript project?**

Following these two pages.

1. [Writing Node.js applications in Clojure and using NPM packages](https://bien.ee/blog/writing-nodejs-applications-in-clojure-using-npm-packages) Backend (express.js)
2. [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs) Frontend (reagent, react)

Both of them are similar, create a new cljs project with `npx create-cljs-project {project-name}`. However, these are two individual projects, can I write frontend and backend application in a same project, if it is possible, how to manage repl in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the entire system is designed to combine as many things as you like. Just configure multiple builds in the `shadow-cljs.edn` `:builds` map.

If you already have both separate projects just take the .cljs files and move them to the other. Then take the build config and also move it into the other `shadow-cljs.edn`.

You may either control multiple builds from the shadow-cljs UI or the command line. All build relevant commands allow you to specify multiple builds (eg. `npx shadow-cljs watch backend frontend`, with the `:frontend` and `:backend` builds in `shadow-cljs.edn`).

You can use namespaces to properly "categorize" your project. I generally have something like `my.app.ui` or `my.app.frontend` for frontend related things and something like `my.app.server` or `my.app.backend`.

With the `watch` for both builds running you can just switch between the REPLs in your editor. From the command line you can just `npx shadow-cljs cljs-repl frontend` or `npx shadow-cljs cljs-repl backend`. Or switch between them from a Clojure REPL via `npx shadow-cljs clj-repl` and then `(shadow/repl :frontend)`. That'll bring you into the CLJS REPL for the `:frontend` build. You may exit that via `:cljs/quit`, which brings you back to the CLJ REPL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can I find an existing project for reference?